# Docker-machine not connecting to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, digital-ocean

I am using `docker` to deploy my `rails` application on `digitalcoean`. I am now unable to connect to my server using  `eval $(docker-machine env my-server)` command.

it shows the following error

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the 
certs: There was an error validating certificates for host 
"207:322:414:35:2376": tls: DialWithDialer timed out
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate- 
certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might 
stop running containers.
```

I also tried to generates the `certs` by using command

`docker-machine regenerate-certs my-server`

`Certs` are generated successfully.

After this when I try to connect to my server by using the following command

```
eval $(docker-machine env my-server)
```

I again receive the above-mentioned error.

```
Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the 
certs: There was an error validating certificates for host 
"207:322:414:35:2376": tls: DialWithDialer timed out
You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate- 
certs [name]'.
Be advised that this will trigger a Docker daemon restart which might 
stop running containers.
enter code here
```

Please help! :'(

Answer (score 1):

Try using the new flag --client-certs:

docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs [name]

And take a look at https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/4401#issuecomment-368670971

Comment: I tried to generate certs with --client-certs tag but got the following error
`GET https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets/41455212: 401 Unable to authenticate you.`

Comment: Now after running above mentioned command to generate certs i got this status

`Error getting SSH command to check if the daemon is up: ssh command error:
command : sudo docker version
err     : exit status 1
output  : Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
`